# How to format this kind of timestamp returned by microsoft academic rest api?

Tags: php, api, rest, format, timestamp

ALL
I am confused about the date field returned by microsoft academic rest api:

JSON Example:

```
{
"AbstractSubmissionDate" : "/Date(-62135568000000-0800)/"
}
```

I don't think this is a standard GMT format, could someone please provide some guidance about how to format this timestamp in PHP or JS , it will be appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The format is milliseconds since the epoch, and then the GMT offset.